# Path of file that will be in the publish directory

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, reflection

Hello i want to know how can i open a file   that at runtime  in `Release` mode will be in the same directory with the `dll` that is executing.More specifically i am deploying the `.NET Core` application with `docker` and i am already copying the `publish` folder.In this folder i will also copy my `file`.

So the folder at runtime will look like:

```
-Publish
 - Executing.dll
 - myfile
 - Microsoft.Package 1
 - Microsoft.Package 2
 .....................
```

From code i want to get the `file`.What will the path be to reach it?Do i need `System.Reflection`?

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk
WORKDIR /app  
COPY . /app    //the file will be here in .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet","publish/Server.dll"]
EXPOSE 8300
```

Answer (score 0):

There're several ways to do that. Using the `Assembly` works for me :

```
var loc1 = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
var loc2 = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
```